# Jquery automatic modal popup

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

HI,

Does anyone know the example of jQuery pop up modal window where you can open automatically on page load and close it after 10 sec for example. Which supports iframe integration. Thank you

Comment: http://www.thewhyandthehow.com/jquery-modal-dialog/

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI modal dialog will automatically open on page load if you declare no other parameters in its initialisation call:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

To have the dialog close after a delay you should be able to include a call further down your DOM ready event:

```
setTimeout($('#dialog').dialog('close'), 10000);
```

Comment: setTimeout($('#dialog').dialog('close'), 10000); It's executes right away without timer

Comment: setTimeout takes a block of text to later run you need to do `setTimeout("$('#dialog').dialog('close')", 10000);`

Answer (score 0):

not sure what are you trying to show in your pop up modal window, but you can try using [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/api) which have a close function even from the iframe.

thus you can just set a timer function to run for ten seconds after the user clicks on it and close the window.